# How to authenticate without database in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have tried the following code to authenticate in Laravel 5.2. But I don't know how to make login true. I tried `Auth::login(true)` after if statement but it is not working properly. I have found some articles about this topic but i couldn't find a detailed example.

```
public static function Login($email,$password)
{
    $fp = fsockopen ( "www.mydomain.com" , 110 );
    if (!$fp) {
        return "Connection Error";
    }
    $trash = fgets ( $fp, 128 );
    fwrite ( $fp, "USER ".$email."\r\n" );
    $trash = fgets ( $fp, 128 );
    fwrite ( $fp, "PASS ".$password."\r\n" );
    $result = fgets ( $fp, 128 );
    if(substr ( $result, 0, 3 ) == '+OK')
        return true; //user will be logged in and then redirect
    else
        return false;
}
```

If it is possible, could you please add a code here that how to make auth true?

P.S. I can retrieve the user information using email with a simple query after login.

Comment: This is a cool question. You need to create your own [Authentication provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers), and then use the logic provided in the post to this provider.

Comment: I think I need a detailed code example. I read it again and again but I couldn't achieve it :(

Comment: I think you can use Laravel's **HTTP Basic Authentication** https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#http-basic-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know who the user is (IE: have a $user instance already), you can simply login without using any guards as shown in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#other-authentication-methods)

```
Auth::login($user);
```

I would pass in a User instance instead of $email/$password to your function

```
$user = User::whereEmail($email)->first();
$class->login($user);
```

and then in your class

```
public static function Login(User $user)
{
    // ...
    if(substr ( $result, 0, 3 ) == '+OK')
        Auth::login($user);
        return true; //user will be logged in and then redirect
    else
        return false;
}
```